# Normalize drawing in FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

In short, I'm making an app where people can collaborate and draw over an image.

I have a proof-of-concept right now, but I've noticed that the drawings show up with incorrect scale on the other person's browser if the two people collaborating are using different sized windows.

---

The solution is to normalize the drawing input so that points are expressed as a percentage of the canvas that they span, instead of absolute pixel values.  However, I don't know how to do this in FabricJS.  Finally, I need to be certain that the solution works when zoomed as well.

Any advice for normalizing drawing input would be appreciated!  For reference, here is my code so far.

**Be warned: I've never used FabricJS before, so this code sample is a mashup of several blog posts and SO answers.  *This is not good code* and will be refactored entirely if FabricJS is the library I decide to go with**

The important lines have been commented

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const room = window.location.href.split('/').pop();
  const socket = io.connect();

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.emit('room', room);
  });

  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('map', {
    isDrawingMode: true
  });

  let size = Math.min(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  canvas.setHeight(size);
  canvas.setWidth(size);

  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function () {
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(img.src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
      width: canvas.width,
      height: canvas.height,
    });
  };
  img.src = "/images/map.jpg";

  canvas.wrapperEl.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    if (e.deltaY <= 0) {
      canvas.zoomToPoint({
        x: e.offsetX,
        y: e.offsetY
      }, canvas.getZoom() * 1.1);
    } else {
      canvas.zoomToPoint({
        x: e.offsetX,
        y: e.offsetY
      }, canvas.getZoom() * 0.9);
    }
  });

  canvas.on('path:created', function (e) {
    // This is where I need to normalize the path data
    canvas.remove(fabric.Path.fromObject(JSON.stringify(e.path)));
    socket.emit('draw_line', {
      line: e.path.toJSON(),
      room: room
    });
  });

  socket.on('draw_line', function (path) {
    // This is where I need to convert the path data from percentages to real size
    fabric.util.enlivenObjects([path], function (objects) {
      objects.forEach(function (o) {
        canvas.add(o);
      });
    });
  });

  var panning = false;
  canvas.on('mouse:up', function (e) {
    panning = false;
  });
  canvas.on('mouse:out', function (e) {
    panning = false;
  });
  canvas.on('mouse:down', function (e) {
    panning = true;
  });
  canvas.on('mouse:move', function (e) {
    //allowing pan only if the image is zoomed.
    if (panning && e && e.e && e.e.shiftKey) {
      var delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY);
      canvas.relativePan(delta);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A general working solution is that you give your drawing board a virtual fixed dimension:

15.000 x 15.000 for example.

Then in each client app you make the canvas as big as you want, for example 1000 x 1000 and another will get 800 x 800.

Setting the canvas zoom to each one will make possible to see the drawing as big as needed mantaining the same point values on the 15.000 space coordinates.

The drawing thickness will probably change with zoom level.

`canvas.setZoom(1000/15000)` and `canvas.setZoom(800/15000)` should be enough.

If it does not work, there is a bug somewhere, that should be fixed.